# Google spreadsheet authentication granularity

Tags: authentication, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I have an admin user(full authentication and some other users who are viewers only).
Now it turns out that I need to allow those viewers to allow access to only a few cells with in a specific sheet.

is there a way I can do this with connecting the spreadsheet to google app engine.

I do not want to convert the whole project to some other database to have a more granule access level control.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Does this [conversation thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/yk33Ly_oIKs) answer your question?

Comment: @MousumiRoy Unfortunetly not. I wanna a give access to a cell but the whole private sheet. Person who will be able to edit just a cell without write access to the sheet.

Comment: Have you considered using permissions within the sheet with [Protect content in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en)?

Comment: @Kessy I didn't know that existed. I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks a bunch

Comment: HI, did you manage to achieve what you were looking for with the last comment? If so, can you set it as an answer so more people can benefit from it?